# Mongo installation through brew causes this connection refused error

Tags: mongodb

[Commands I entered to installl mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX772.png)

However following the installation instructions I dont get the line after I run mongod [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017, I think the error might be to do with setting permissions for the data directory?